# Problem with the application of the pigeonhole principle.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

A football team plays at least one match per day in a month of $30$ days , but no more than $45$ matches in that month. Is it true that in some consecutive days in the month, the team will play exactly $14$ matches ?

Comment: Consider one of the possibilities: first 15 days -- 1 match each day, next 15 days -- 2 matches each day. So, there can be 14 consecutive days with exactly 14 matches.

Comment: Let $a_i$ - number of matches played on day $i$. Let $s_i=a_1+\cdots+a_i$.   

$$1\le s_1<s_2<\cdots<s_{30}\le 45$$  

$$14\le s_1+14<s_2+14<\cdots<s_{30}+14\le 59$$

By pigeonhole principle exist $i>j$ such that $s_i=s_j+14$.

Comment: Above comment summarizes N.F.Taussig's answer in a hint. It's not the first time I'm seeing this problem and it's probably the best way of solving it. No one upvoted his answer, so maybe it's a bit too lengthy for others and no one bothered to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_k$ denote the number of football matches the team has played after $k$ days.  Since the team plays at least one match per day, the sequence $\{a_k\}$ is strictly increasing.  Moreover, since the team plays at most $45$ matches in the month of $30$ days, $a_{30} \leq 45$.  Consider the sequence defined by $b_k = a_k + 14$.  Then the sequence $\{b_k\}$ is also strictly increasing.  Moreover, $b_{30} \leq 45 + 14 = 59$.  Consider the union of the sequences $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$.  It has $60$ terms, each of which is a positive integer which does not exceed $59$.  Hence, by the Pigeonhole Principle, there exist $i, j$, with $i > j$, such that $a_i = b_j = a_j + 14$, which means that there is a stretch of $i - j$ consecutive days in which the team plays exactly $14$ matches.