# Split $n \ge 45$ into 30 positive integers and prove there exists some consecutive numbers whose sum is 14

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Literally, there is an integer sequence $A = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_{30}\}$. Given that $30\le\sum_ia_i\le45$ and $a_i > 0$, prove that $\exists c\le d(\sum_{i=c}^da_i=14)$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Ditto. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: If it's different than the title, perhaps change the title...

Comment: Sorry. Title have be changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with the application of the pigeonhole principle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327555/problem-with-the-application-of-the-pigeonhole-principle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $A_i = \sum_{j=1}^i a_i$.
Consider the numbers $ A_1, A_2, \ldots A_{30}$ and $ A_1 + 14, A_2 + 14, \ldots A_{30} + 14$.

How many numbers are there?
How many possible values could they take?

What technique in discrete math (which you tagged with) seems the most likely for us to use?
What happens when you apply this technique?

---

Hence, conclude that there is some consecutive string that sum to exactly 14.